# Repository pattern with EF Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I am not grasping something when creating my repository pattern with EF Code First. If I want to abstract out EF I would have to make my repository be of type IObjectContextAdapter, no? That is what DbContext implements. If I later switch to use something like NHibernate or some other 3rd party ORM, it may not implement IObjectContextAdapter.

Is my only solution to create a wrapper that wraps the ORM and does return an implementation of IObjectContextAdapter? If so, what is the point?

Comment: I'm not following the logic that the repository needs to be of type `IObjectContextAdapter`.  Maybe some sample code will help.

Comment: Will add a code sample soon but in the meantime, I just meant if I have a class that performs actions on a repository, I would specify a property on the class that is of the abstract type that the repository would have to be. So public IObjectContextAdapter Repository { get; set; } and then in my methods I would just do something like this.Repository.Save(); etc

Comment: I still don't follow.  Why not define an interface `IRepository` that has a `Save`, then when creating the actual `EFRepository` make a constructor that takes an `IDbContext`.  Hold on to it and use it in the implementation of `IRepository.Save()`.  Then, your property is defined `public IRepository Repository { get; set; }` etc.

Comment: Ok sorry and what does IDbContext do? And this means that if I want to share business logic and not have to copy them between each implementation that I should then create another layer that I use to wrap the repository, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you have to implement `IObjectContextAdapter` when creating a repository pattern with EF.  The main difference between using EF or something like NHibernate will be how to wrap either the `DbContext` or the `ISession` respectively.

Here is a sketch of how an EF code-first repository could be written:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    void Save();
}


public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> entitySet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.entitySet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        return this.entitySet.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This allows the actual `DbContext` to be injected.

Comment: What is IDbContext? NHibernate implements that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant DbContext.  updating now.

Comment: Ok so you're saying in my EF implementation I could make the constructor take a DbContext and in my other implementations I could make it take something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  For NHibernate, you would take an `ISession` etc.